# When converting from byte array to string it is adding spaces

Tags: c#, serialization, rabbitmq, nsjsonserialization

I am using RabbitMq and I am able to add a string to the queue just fine. When I look in the queue everything looks good, but when I bring that string off the queue it is adding spaces between each character. I have looked at everything from using .trim() and different types of encoding. The string ALWAYS comes out with spaces, which makes it impossible to deserialize into json.

Since it is sitting on the queue correct, I am just adding the part that gets the data and converts it into a simple string.

```
 using (var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
      using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
      {

        channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, false, consumer);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
          var body = ea.Body;
          var message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body, 0, body.Length);
          Console.WriteLine($" [x] Recieved {message}");
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, "brandon", false, false, null, consumer);
        Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

Comment: We are also using a .net core project

Comment: Is it possible that the incoming message is UTF-16 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Sounds like the bytes may be stored as unicode.  Try changing the UTF8 to Unicode.

Comment: Bingo @TwistedStem, I did it the other way around, changed the encoding the UTF8 and it worked like a charm! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when the message was being encoded it was encoded as unicode. I changed the encoding to UTF8 and the message came across perfect :)